# Como fazer o memcache apontar para 127.0.0.1 no windows 10?

Tags: php, memcached

Estou tentando fazer com que o meu `memcached` server aponte para o endereço `127.0.0.1`, porém quando vou rodar minha aplicação aparece o erro:

> Notice: MemcachePool::add(): Server 10.203.10.76 (tcp 11211, udp 0) 
>   failed with: Uma tentativa de conexão falhou porque o componente
>   conectado não respondeu corretamente após um período de tempo ou a
>   conexão estabelecida falhou porque o host conectado não respondeu.
>   (10060)

Comment: Coloque mais detalhes do seu ambiente. Você esta usando o apache instalado no windows? Ou usando algum servidor tipo wamp xamp? De uma olhada neste post do SOen: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10804940/1997073

Comment: Você está usando IPV6? Windows ou Linux?